# How can i override a:before propertie-value in/from my Html file

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

This is my code:

```css
li a:before {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 11px 5px 11px 0;
  border-color: transparent #d9d9d9 transparent transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://amino.dk"> </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now I want to override the color wich is defined in my css `a:before { border-color: transparent #d9d9d9 transparent transparent; }` from my html file.

I want my users to chose which color they like.

I want override border-color in Html and dont want to remove li a::before from my css.

I think somthin like that:

```
< a href="http://Amino.dk" style="border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;">
```

Comment: Don't get it, want to add color picker ? Or there is already a color that you want to override without changing css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use `<style>` tags for that anywhere in the HTML responsible to render that page. I have an example snippet for you:

```
<style>
  li a:before {
    border-color: #333; /* Or any other color you want in the borders */
  }
</style>
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: I want override border-color in Html and dont want to remove li a::before from my css.

I think somthin like that:

< a href="http://Amino.dk" style="border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;">

Comment: Well, you can not use pseudo classes (:before, :after, :hover etc.) as inline styles. Instead, you may use an additional HTML element, called `<style>` and provide the modifications within this tag (as I already wrote in the answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can always overwrite CSS styles by using a `style` tag in your `a`-tag.

Give your users a choice of colours, get the selected colour via JavaScript and pass it to your `a`-tag  inside a variable.

This should do the trick:

```
<a href="http://Amino.dk" style="border-color: transparent red transparent transparent">
```

Comment: I want override border-color in Html and dont want to remove li a::before from my css.

I think somthin like that:

< a href="http://Amino.dk" style="border-color: transparent red transparent transparent;">

Comment: Just remove the semicolon behind your redirect target and it should work